How do I remove a wheel axle with smooth circular bolts?
How do I remove an axle like the one on the picture below? It's a 12 inch wheel from a vintage children's push bike that I would like to refurbish. The bolts that seem to hold the axle in place are completely smooth and circular on both sides.


This is a cup and cone hub. There are hubs where the cone on one side does not move but I've never seen a hub where the cones on both sides don't move. Once side should have flats so that a wrench can be used. Once side must unscrew or there wouldn't be slop in the bearing adjustment. The bearings are visible so one side or the other unscrewed at some time.

Once you get one cone nut off, please add some more photos.  New bearing balls are a good idea, and It may be worth replacing the whole rear axle+nuts with a modern one.

These are called cones. Usually they have wrench flats. They also usually are paired with a locknut on each side, though some very old hubs eschew that. I'm speculating here but I think one of two things is likely true:

The cones here simply get tightened down against the ends of the threads cut into the axle, disallowing any adjustment. If this is true you probably just need to find a way of gripping them and torquing them.
When assembled initially, an adjustment was done to make the hub as loose as possible with no free play, but instead of locking the adjustment in place mechanically as is the norm, it was done with glue or solder on the threads. In other words, a cheap, hardware-minimal permanent adjustment that also works well with the narrow OLD most hubs of this sort need to exist in.

If this is an aesthetic restoration you probably want to use aluminum, brass, or another soft metal to grip with. The choices basically are either round blocks that match the radius, as in a pedal or axle vise, or a pair of v-blocks of some sort. I'd probably approach this by putting one Park AV-5 into a vise to grip it in whichever of its grooves gets the best purchase, then holding another AV-5 in hand with a Knipex Plierwrench and seeing if turns that way. If not, put heat on it to undo the glue or solder theorized above, and then do the same.


Thank you Nathan, this is exactly what I was afraid of :) Unfortunately I only have very minimal equipment consisting of hand tools so this will have to wait till I get an access to a vise - and then still I'll have to somehow diy the mentioned Park tool. I find a bit frustrating that some manufacturer would choose this locking mechanism as a viable solution.

Another option I should mention is making some simple wood v-blocks to grip them with, or even leather. If you have vise grips you could do it by clamping them around the blocks or the leather and see what happens.

A slight refinement to the wooden V blocks: drill a hole of the diameter of the cone in piece of wood.  Saw the wood into 2 pieces across the hole, which removes enough material that you can press the halves on.  Now you have a wooden version of the block above, ready to put in a vice.  The other end may need some shaping to fit the jaws of your other tool

And instead of leather, heatshrink sleeving can be used, on the tool, the part, or even both
